# Regular expression to check if the google font link is valid?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches a google font link element.

For ex :- `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: href with  `fonts.googleapis.com` in it, yes ? what regex engine usifng ?

Comment: Using traditional NFA. Posted a regex that works for me. Let me know if it can be improved.

Comment: did nont answer qestin, how make if valid ? otherwise it just string compare `==`

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression can be used to check a valid google font link.

`<link \s*?href="\http(s):\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/css2\?family=(?!\')([\x21-\x7e]*)\" \s*?rel=\"stylesheet\"\s*?>`

[Click to verify regex](https://regexr.com/56g3r)